# .NET 5 OS-specific TFMs not supported by CLI 'dotnet new classlib' command

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to create a new .NET 5 C# classlib project using the dotnet CLI as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#classlib

(Using the developer console - I have the latest VS2019 (16.8.5) installed with the .NET SDK workload).

If I specify the «framework» param as 'net5.0' it works fine:

**dotnet new classlib -f net5.0**

However the page linked above has a link to a list of frameworks, which recommends the OS-specific TFM ('net5.0-windows'):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#suggested-targets

**dotnet new classlib -f net5.0-windows**

But when I try to use that I get the following error

> 'net5.0-windows' is not a valid value for -f (Framework).

Is this just a case of the templates not being caught up with the latest guidance, or am I missing something here about the dotnet CLI and TFMs?

**dotnet --info** gives the following:

> .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
> Version:   5.0.103
> Commit:    72dec52dbd
>
> Runtime Environment:
> OS Name:     Windows
> OS Version:  10.0.19042
> OS Platform: Windows
> RID:         win10-x64
> Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\
>
> Host (useful for support):
> Version: 5.0.3
> Commit:  c636bbdc8a
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.512 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.513 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.515 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.701 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.2.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: Can you share the result from running `dotnet --info`? Also, that page you linked says to use `net5.0-windows` only when it's an *OS-specific* classlib. You should try and use the `net5.0` TFM if the library is platform-agnostic.

Comment: @omajid Thanks for your reply.  I added the `dotnet --info` output to the post, and yes I am planning to use windows-specific functionality (the library will be used by WPF applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet new` command uses .NET Core template engine. `classlib` is one of the templates out of the box, and you could find its definition [here](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/master/template_feed/Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.5.0/content/ClassLibrary-CSharp/.template.config/template.json).

By default, `dotnet new classlib` only supports `choices` for the `framework` switch from all installed templates, that for example on my machine, the value has to be one of:

```
net5.0            - Target net5.0
netstandard2.1    - Target netstandard2.1
netstandard2.0    - Target netstandard2.0
netcoreapp3.1     - Target netcoreapp3.1
netcoreapp3.0     - Target netcoreapp3.0
netcoreapp2.1     - Target netcoreapp2.1
```

You can use `dotnet new classlib --help` to find out your options.

However, you could always override the targeting framework using `--target-framework-override` switch which is a hidden switch for `dotnet new classlib`:

```
dotnet new classlib --target-framework-override net5.0-windows
```

The command creates a `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Having that said, alternatively, you could always manually modify `TargetFramework` in the `csproj` file created to target to OS-specific framework.